# How to bind time in grails 3?

Tags: grails, data-binding, grails3

In grails 3 is there a way to bind time of format "11:00 AM" to java.sql.Time?

```
import java.sql.Time


Time startTime
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.  One is to supply an appopriate `ValueConverter` as described in the **Custom Data Converters** section at http://docs.grails.org/3.3.8/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding.

That could look something like this...

```
package com.myapp.converters

import grails.databinding.converters.ValueConverter
import java.sql.Time

/**
 * A custom converter which will convert String into a Time object.
 */
class TimeValueConverter implements ValueConverter {

    boolean canConvert(value) {
        value instanceof String
    }

    def convert(value) {
        // return a new Time instance initialized with the `value` parameter
    }

    Class<?> getTargetType() {
        java.sql.Time
    }
}
```

Then add an instance of that class the Spring application context:

```
beans = {
    timeConverter com.myapp.converters.TimeValueConverter
    // ...
}
```